# Is there a way to prevent a class from being derived from twice using a static assert and type trait?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, type-traits, static-assert

I realize this is a contrived example, but I want a compile check to prevent this...

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

class D : public B, public C
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_base_of_once<A,D>::value))
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that `A` has this property if `A -> B` is OK but `A -> B -> C` is not? (I write `X -> Y` to mean that `X` is a base of `Y`.)

Comment: Do you mean something like `D1 -> B; D2 -> B; D3 -> D1, D2;`?

Comment: So you're trying to come up with a compile-time mechanism to prohibit the diamond pattern (when not using virtual inheritance), basically.

Comment: I guess that would be a correct assessment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: give the guy some space.  If you want to go crazy editing questions, we have *plenty* of *awful* ones coming through daily.

Comment: @Will: Please don't publicly berate me if you're going to remove my rationale and supporting comments and then remove my ability to defend myself. And I _do_ edit _awful_ questions daily; which questions I choose to devote my precious time editing for free is up to me, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(((A*)(D*)0 == 0))
```

If A exists twice, this should rise an ambiguity error, while otherwise the test will always succeed (because it compares two null pointers).

Answer (score 0):

When I try to derive a class twice as you have here it does not even compile. (duplicate base type)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to, you an test both your base classes:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

class D : public B, public C
{
    static_assert(!(is_base_of<A,B>::value && is_base_of<A,C>::value),
                   "Invalid inheritance!");
};
```

Otherwise you can make the classes inherit virtually from A, so that there will still only be one instance of it in the derived class:

```
class A {};
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};

class D : public B, public C
{
    // only one A here
};
```